# How to integrate Fisglobal(World Payment Gateway) Express Tokenized Payment API in my web application?

Tags: rest, payment-gateway, worldpay

I'm trying to integrate Fisglobal Express Tokenized Payment API in my web application but I'm having trouble getting started. I've searched for the documentation but I'm still not sure how to proceed.

Can someone provide me with a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction for integrating Fisglobal Express Tokenized Payment in my web application? Any sample code or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conducting extensive research and seeking support from the payment gateway, I have discovered a step-by-step process to achieve the desired outcome. Below is the code to implement this process.

1. Generate Token(Pass)

URL: https://certservices.elementexpress.com/

Method: POST

XML:

```
<PaymentAccountCreate xmlns="https://services.elementexpress.com">
<Credentials>
    <AccountID>{{AccountID}}</AccountID>
    <AccountToken>{{AccountToken}}</AccountToken>
    <AcceptorID>{{AcceptorID}}</AcceptorID>
</Credentials>
<Application>
    <ApplicationID>{{ApplicationID}}</ApplicationID>
    <ApplicationName>XML Test Example</ApplicationName>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.00</ApplicationVersion>
</Application>
<PaymentAccount>
<PaymentAccountType>0</PaymentAccountType>
<PaymentAccountReferenceNumber>12345</PaymentAccountReferenceNumber>
</PaymentAccount>
<Card>
    <CardNumber>343434343434343</CardNumber>
    <ExpirationMonth>12</ExpirationMonth>
    <ExpirationYear>25</ExpirationYear>
    <CVV>123</CVV>
</Card>
```

2. Transaction with CreditSale Method.

URL: https://certtransaction.elementexpress.com

Method: POST

XML:

```
    <CreditCardSale xmlns="https://transaction.elementexpress.com">
        <Credentials>
            <AccountID>{{AccountID}}</AccountID>
            <AccountToken>{{AccountToken}}</AccountToken>
            <AcceptorID>{{AcceptorID}}</AcceptorID>
        </Credentials>
        <Application>
            <ApplicationID>{{ApplicationID}}</ApplicationID>
            <ApplicationName>XML Test Example</ApplicationName>
            <ApplicationVersion>1.00</ApplicationVersion>
        </Application>
        <Transaction>
            <TransactionAmount>100.00</TransactionAmount>
            <MarketCode>0</MarketCode>
            <ReferenceNumber>123456</ReferenceNumber>
            <TicketNumber>123456</TicketNumber>
            <PartialApprovedFlag>1</PartialApprovedFlag>
            <DuplicateCheckDisableFlag>1</DuplicateCheckDisableFlag>
            <PaymentType>2</PaymentType>
            <SubmissionType>0</SubmissionType>
            <NetworkTransactionID></NetworkTransactionID>
        </Transaction>
        <Terminal>
            <TerminalID>01</TerminalID>
            <TerminalType>0</TerminalType>
            <TerminalCapabilityCode>0</TerminalCapabilityCode>
            <TerminalEnvironmentCode>0</TerminalEnvironmentCode>
            <CardPresentCode>0</CardPresentCode>
            <CVVPresenceCode>0</CVVPresenceCode>
            <CardInputCode>0</CardInputCode>
            <CardholderPresentCode>0</CardholderPresentCode>
            <MotoECICode>0</MotoECICode>
        </Terminal>
        <PaymentAccount>
            <PaymentAccountType>0</PaymentAccountType>
            <PaymentAccountID>DD2C8150-3695-4F49-93A1-1FA7F6C8CED3</PaymentAccountID>
            <PaymentAccountReferenceNumber>123</PaymentAccountReferenceNumber>
        </PaymentAccount>
    </CreditCardSale>
```

Replace the credentials in the code block or configuration file with the values enclosed in double curly braces.

Comment: That is what I was looking for a couple of weeks. You did a great job. Thank you